# Use variable as EventStream or Property in Bacon.js

Tags: javascript, variables, hash, properties, bacon.js

I'm new to Bacon.js and I'm trying a lot to figure out how it works. So, is there a way to use variable, for example the hash from the URL, as if it would be an EventStream of `onVariableChange` events. Sorry if what I'm writing is awkward.

Here is my Code:

```
var hash =  window.location.hash.slice(1, window.location.hash.length);

newdata = hash.asEventStream("change").onValue( function(){**do_something_with_new_hash_value();**
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asEventStream` creates an Bacon.js EventStream from a jQuery event. So you can you only apply it to a jQuery object, not to a JavaScript variable. So in your case you can use the jQuery/HTML5 event `hashchange` to create an EventStream from its changes:

```
$(window).asEventStream('hashchange')
         .map(function () { return window.location.hash; });
```

There is no way to convert a variable by itsself to a EventStream or Property, because there needs to be a way to notify about changes, which normal variables do not supply. However, you can use a `Bacon.Bus` to create an EventStream or Property, given that you call `push` whenever the variables changes.

Comment: Dude, you're awesome! That's more than what I was looking for.